# C++ how to check the signature of a template parameter class at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

In the code below, I am trying to check the signature of the class that is passed as the second template argument to `WTrajectory`. In the current implementation, the constructor of `WTrajectory` compares the types of the template argument `T` and the template argument of the type that is passed to it as the second argument.

The current implementation can perform the check. However, I would prefer to perform it at compile time, if it is possible. Moreover, I would also like to check if the template argument `TWPoint` has a member function `returnTimeTypeID`, also at compile time (a solution that performs this check at run time can be found here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)).

```
template<typename T>
struct WPoint
{
    const std::type_info& returnTimeTypeID(void) const
        {return typeid(T);}
};

template<typename T, typename TWPoint>
struct WTrajectory
{
    WTrajectory(const TWPoint& wp)
        {
            compare_types(wp);
        }

    void compare_types(const TWPoint& wp)
        {
            if (typeid(T) != wp.returnTimeTypeID())
                throw std::runtime_error("Error");
        }
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to check exactly? The wording makes it seem like you're just trying to check that `TWPoint` is `WPoint<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `returnTimeTypeID` is non-virtual the compiler will know the dynamic type of `TWPoint` at compile time. So instead of doing a runtime check just change your template:

```
template<typename T>
struct WTrajectory
{
    typedef T TWPoint;
    ...
```

The best way to check whether a template type has a perticular method at compile time is to *just call the method*. You'll get a compilation error if it doesn't provide the needed functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If `WPoint` contains more than just the type info, then the following code will work

```
template<typename T>
struct WPoint
{
    // ... stuff not related to type checking
};

template<typename T>
struct WTrajectory
{
    WTrajectory(const WPoint<T>& wp)
        {
        }
};
```

You could remove `WPoint` if it does not contain anything else besides the type info.